# How to make more than one object rotate?

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app and I need to create gravity and rotation for three buttons. I wrote an infinite rotate function for one of my buttons but I don't know how to link it to the other two.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var animator:  UIDynamicAnimator?
    var gravity: UIGravityBehavior?
    var isRotating = false

    @IBOutlet var Ball1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Ball2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Ball3: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)

        if !isRotating {
            // create a spin animation
            let spinAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
            // starts from 0
            spinAnimation.fromValue = 0
            // goes to 360 ( 2 * π )
            spinAnimation.toValue = M_PI*2
            // define how long it will take to complete a 360
            spinAnimation.duration = 1
            // make it spin infinitely
            spinAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
            // do not remove when completed
            spinAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
            // specify the fill mode
            spinAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            // and the animation acceleration
            spinAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
            // add the animation to the button layer
            Ball1.layer.addAnimation(spinAnimation, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")

        } else {
            // remove the animation
            Ball1.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }
        // toggle its state
        isRotating = !isRotating
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the animation layer to your `UIButtons` this way.

```
    Ball2.layer.addAnimation(spinAnimation, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")
    Ball3.layer.addAnimation(spinAnimation, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")
```

and remove them this way

```
 Ball2.layer.removeAllAnimations()
 Ball3.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```